# find command problems in perl script

Tags: perl

I am writing a script that will create a new tar file containing only those files that were created after the previous tar.gz file was created.

```
my $path_to_logs = "/home/myscripts/";
my $FNAME= `ls -t *.tar.gz | head -n1`;
my $FILENAME = $path_to_logs.$FNAME;
chomp ($FILENAME);

if (-e $FILENAME){
     my $changed= `find . -name '*.log'  -newer $FILENAME`;
    chomp $changed;
    $command = "tar -cvzT ". $changed." -f deleteme-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S).tar.gz";
    chomp $command;
    print $command;
    }
```

However, the outout for $command shows that each of the find results are on a new line, so I dont get on concatenated command for tar.  Any idea why?

Thanks.

Comment: "the output for $command shows that each of the find results are on a new line, ... [a]ny idea why?"  That's what `find` does.  You might have a version of `find` that acts differently when called interactively than when called from a shell script or other program (`ls` often does that).

Answer (score 0):

Just transform the output from `find` into a single line:

```
 my $changed= `find . -name '*.log'  -newer $FILENAME`;
chomp $changed;

$changed =~ s/\n/ /g;

$command = "tar -cvzT -f deleteme-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S).tar.gz " . $changed;
```

Btw, in general, it's often better to reduce one's dependency on OS specific features.  You can duplicate all of the commands that you're shelling to the OS in perl using not too much effort:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use File::Find::Rule;
use File::stat;
use Time::Piece;

my $path_to_logs = "/home/myscripts/";

my ($FILENAME) = sort {
    stat($a)->mtime <=> stat($b)->mtime
} glob('/home/myscripts/*.tar.gz');

if (-e $FILENAME){
    my $modified = stat($FILENAME)->mtime;

    my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                                ->name('*.log')
                                ->modified(">$modified")
                                ->in('.');

    my $datenow = localtime->strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S');

    my $command = "tar -cvzT -f deleteme-${datenow}.tar.gz ". join(' ', @files);
```

You could even use [`Archive::Tar`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive%3a%3aTar) instead of `/bin/tar`, but that would potentially have a performance hit.

However, regardless, these simple changes make your script much more portable, and didn't require that much additional code.

Answer (score 0):

How about this to solve your immediate problem:

```
my $find_cmd = "find . -name '*.log' -newer $filename";
open my $in, '-|', $find_cmd or die "Couldn't run command. $!\n";
while(<$in>) {
  chomp;
  print "Do something with file: $_\n";
}
```

If you need the files in a single line you can create a variable and concatenate them or whatever, I just wanted to show you a better way to call a system command (it would be even better if you could call the command directly without the shell expansion but you are relying on the shell expansion there).

In the long run you might want to learn how to use perl's own find/wanted routine and how to do dir globbing instead of having to rely so much on the system.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make much sense to do this in Perl anyway.  Regardless of the wrapper language, it would be simpler and more robust to pipe the `find` output straight to `tar`, which knows how to handle it.

Anyway, your use of `tar`'s `-T` option is wrong.  It expects a file name containing file names, one per line, not a list of file names.

Also, your `FNAME` contains the newest file in the current directory, where apparently the intent is to find the newest file in `/home/myscripts`.

Finally, the `$(date ...)` interpolation will not be interpolated by Perl, but trivially works if you convert this (back?) to a shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
path_to_logs = "/home/myscripts/"
FNAME=$(cd "$path_to_logs"; ls -t *.tar.gz | head -n1)
FILENAME = "$path_to_logs/$FNAME"

if [ -e "$FILENAME" ]; then
    find . -name '*.log'  -newer "$FILENAME" |
    tar -c -v -z -T - -f deleteme-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S).tar.gz
fi
```